# print unicode to LPT1 dot matrix printer using .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, unicode, printing

I have 8 dot matrix printers with LPT port only. I have to print 6 Lacs bills per month. Major problem is that the data to be printed is in unicode now.I am using Code :

```
Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL As Short = &H80
Public Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Short = -1
Public Const GENERIC_READ As UInteger = &H80000000L
Public Const GENERIC_WRITE As UInteger = &H40000000
Public Const CREATE_NEW As UInteger = 1
Public Const CREATE_ALWAYS As UInteger = 2
Public Const OPEN_EXISTING As UInteger = 3

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Shared Function CreateFile(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As UInteger, ByVal dwShareMode As UInteger, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As UInteger, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As UInteger, ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Shared Sub sendTextToLPT1(ByVal receiptText As String)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = CreateFile("LPT1", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
    ' Is bad handle? INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE 
    If ptr.ToInt32() = -1 Then
        ' ask the framework to marshall the win32 error code to an exception 
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error())
    Else
        Dim lpt As New FileStream(ptr, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
        buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(receiptText)
        lpt.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        lpt.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Unable to print unicode hindi text using this code.
 How can i print unicode Hindi data to LPT port?

Comment: does your printer have unicode font support? If not, you'll have to render the job on the computer and send it as a graphic job, not text.

Comment: i have an epson 2175. How can i came to know, if it supports unicode font?   Thanks in advance...

Comment: write out a unicode code as raw text to lpt1. if you get the actual character, then the print knows unicode (of course, that doesn't say that the font being used has all the glyphs you need to use). If you get multiple chars, including wonky accented chars, then it doesn't do unicode.

Comment: I tried the code above and pass unicode string to it. but it prints garbage characters. It has SanSarif, USH, HSD, DRAFT in Font Option. what to do?

Comment: @MarcB How to render a graphic and send it to a LPT printer? prepare the graphic then send as binary file? in bitmap file format? Any link is welcome.